# Is it appropriate to ask this on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I would like to gather opinions on how to evaluate the monetary value of a website. Is this an appropriate question to ask on SO?

**Edit:**

Please consider that this is directly related to my job as web developer. I have been offered equity in the company, and need to know how to act.

Comment: edit the question to be 'how can i write a program to evaluate the monetary value of a website' and then it's programming-related ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uh,          no.

Edit: Still no.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I'd ask first :)

Comment: Not a problem, I'm here to help :)

Comment: +2 because this is two answers.

Comment: Two no's make a yes?

Answer (score 4):

[I agree with Eric](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13816/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-this-on-stackoverflow/13817#13817), and refer you to [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> #### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> ...
> Oh yes, and it should be about programming. You know, with a computer.

#### Please see:

[Where can I ask questions that aren’t programming questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions)